# Why do the successive ionisation energies of Ni and Pt diverge?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, periodic-trends

The data I am referring to is below on the graph. The explanation I have found is that the 5d orbital of Pt is more diffuse than the 3d orbital of Ni, so is less sensitive to the increases in Z<sub>eff</sub> as we remove successive electrons. This seems somehow incomplete though, so I was wondering if anyone has any further insight?

[image]